# What do I need to know about investing in developing countries?

Tags: investing, risk, sri-lanka

My wife is Sri Lankan and we have some cash assets there, but we both live in Australia.

Sri Lanka has restrictions on taking money out of the country - essentially it looks like you can only take $US10000 each time you leave the country, unless you get special dispensation.

And even then, it looks like the buy/sell spread on LKR is quite big.

We're basically looking at investing in some kind of high-growth-but-not-stock-picking strategy - ie. an index fund.

The idea is, we haven't decided where we will settle down yet, so we're a bit adverse to all savings to Australia off the bat, in case that we need to convert it again later anyway, but also - with the currency restrictions, we likely aren't able to convert all our currency straight away anyway.

There are term deposits available in Sri Lanka, currently paying ~13%p.a - but of course inflation is higher, so this rate is 2-4x inflation - which is comparable to term deposits in Australia.

There are some index funds in Sri Lanka, for example, [this is one of the top results from Google](http://www.ceylonassetmanagement.com/ceylon-index-fund/). However locals have warned me that 'The stock market here doesn't work the way it does elsewhere' - but I'm not sure what that means.

Here are some specific questions:

- What is the best way to take money out of Sri Lanka - also taking into account any taxes you might pay when bringing that money into the new country?
- How risky are index funds in Sri Lanka?
- How likely is the government to confiscate or restrict your Sri Lankan money - is there any examples of this happening in similar countries?
- As a general rule - is currency conversion something that should be put off until later (ie. grow your savings before the fee is applied) or is this basically the same thing.
- As a general risk-vs-reward calculus do developing countries have more-or-less the same ratio as developed countries - or are developing countries inherrently more risky, with the same reward?